# Combinations Practice Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

So, I'm studying for a final for a discrete mathematics course I'm taking. One sample study problem proivded is:
"In how many ways can a photographer at a wedding arrange $7$ people in a row where the bride and the groom are among these people if either the bride or the groom is in the picture but not both?"
I compared this to a previous homework question, and came up with this:

$7! * 2 * \binom{6}{5} = 10080 * 6 = 60480.$

However, the instructor gave no answer sheet with these sample questions, so I'm kinda worried if I'm doing the work properly. Can anyone confirm I'm doing this right?

Comment: I'm not clear on the question - how many people end up in the row?  Are you looking for all row lengths that can be selected from the 7?  (which includes 7 different rows of length 1, but not all of the rows of length 2 - there would be no row of 7 people possible)

Comment: I can't understand the question.  Do you mean to say the bride and groom must be together if they are both in the picture?  Do you have to use all seven people?  Presumably the bride and groom are two of the seven.

Comment: Guess it was worded wrong. I think it means to say that either the bride or the groom can be in the picture, but they both can't be in the picture.

Comment: How many people are we choosing from, and how many people are in the line? - it would seem to me that you might need 6 'others' then a bride and groom, but you always choose exactly one of the couple and mix them with the 6 - I don't see why you are selecting 5 from 6 - no your expression looks wrong - seems to me that it might be 2 x 7! - but this one is all in the wording

Comment: $\binom{2}{1}\cdot\binom{n-2}{7-1}\cdot7!$, where $n$ is the number of people available for the photographer to choose from.